# PHP: preg_replace() "inch" doublequotes with double-singlequotes?

Tags: php, regex

It's been a couple years since I used RegEx, and being fairly novice even back then, I'm getting stumped on what I thought would be an easy one.

I have two data sources which I need to compare, and one has double-quotes `"` denoting inches while the other uses doubled-single-quotes `''`.
As I'm iterating through, I need to convert the single-doubles `"` to double-singles `''`.

I started off playing with `preg_match()`, and once I had a pattern returning `TRUE`, I moved it to `preg_replace()`. Looks like my feeble attempt is not holding up, though.
Let's take a look:

```
$str = 'PRE-301 1/8" ID 48" BX';

preg_replace( '/(\d+)\"/', "\1''", $str );

echo '<pre>',var_dump($str),'</pre>';
```

My goal is to get a `string(24) "PRE-301 1/8'' ID 48'' BX"`. What I am getting, though, is just the original `string(22) "PRE-301 1/8" ID 48" BX"` back.

Comment: You're ignoring the return value of `preg_replace`.

Comment: Is `str_replace('"', "''", $str)` not good enough?

Comment: D'oh!! Rookie mistakes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not assigning the value back, and you need to change `\1` to `$1` in your replacement.

```
$str = preg_replace('/(\d+)"/', "$1''", $str);
```

[**Live Demo**](https://eval.in/165265)

**Note**: You can remove the backslash before your quotes, it's not neccessary here. And if your strings are always like this, you can use just replace the quotes alone using [`str_replace()`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$str = str_replace('"', "''", $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things here.

1. preg_replace doesn't change the string in place, but returns a value. So you are looking for:

   $new_str = preg_replace(...
2. Double quote (and single for that matter) are not metacharacters in Regex, so you are free to leave off the \ in front of the ". It won't hurt anything, but it's a bit more readable, which is nice with Regex!